# How to customize my Solr search result?

Tags: solr

I am using Solr for the following search need:

raw data: in FIX format, it's OK if you don't know what it is, treat it as csv with a special delimiter.

parsed data: from raw data, all in the same format of a bunch of JSON format with all 100+ fields.

Example:

Raw data: delimiter is \u001:

> 8=FIX.4.4 9=653 35=RIO 1=TEST 11=337912000000002 38=1 44=2.0 39=A 40=2
>   49=VIPER 50=JPNIK01 54=1 55=JNI253D8.OS 56=XSVC 59=0 75=20180350
>   100=XOSE 10039=viperooe 10241=viperooe 150=A 372=D
>   122=20180320-08:08:35.038 10066=20180320-08:08:35.038
>   10436=20180320-08:08:35.038 202=25375.0 52=20180320-08:08:35.088
>   60=20180320-08:08:35.088 10071=20180320-08:08:35.088
>   11210=337912000000002 37=337912000000002 10184=337912000000002 201=1
>   29=4 10438=RIO.4.5 10005=178 10515=178 10518=178 581=13 660=102 1133=G
>   528=P 10104=Y 10202=APMKTMAKING 10208=APAC.VIPER.OOE 10217=Y 10292=115
>   11032=-1 382=0 10537=XOSE 15=JPY 167=OPT 48=179492540 455=179492540
>   22=101 456=101 151=1.0 421=JPN 10=200

Parsed data: in json:

> {"122": "20180320-08:08:35.038", "49": "VIPER", "382": "0", "151":
>   "1.0", "9": "653", "10071": "20180320-08:08:35.088", "15": "JPY",
>   "56": "XSVC", "54": "1", "10202": "APMKTMAKING", "10537": "XOSE",
>   "10217": "Y", "48": "179492540", "201": "1", "40": "2", "8":
>   "FIX.4.4", "167": "OPT", "421": "JPN", "10292": "115", "10184":
>   "337912000000002", "456": "101", "11210": "337912000000002", "1133":
>   "G", "10515": "178", "10": "200", "11032": "-1", "10436":
>   "20180320-08:08:35.038", "10518": "178", "11": "337912000000002",
>   "75": "20180320", "10005": "178", "10104": "Y", "35": "RIO", "10208":
>   "APAC.VIPER.OOE", "59": "0", "60": "20180320-08:08:35.088", "528":
>   "P", "581": "13", "1": "TEST", "202": "25375.0", "455": "179492540",
>   "55": "JNI253D8.OS", "100": "XOSE", "52": "20180320-08:08:35.088",
>   "10241": "viperooe", "150": "A", "10039": "viperooe", "39": "A",
>   "10438": "RIO.4.5", "38": "1", "37": "337912000000002", "372": "D",
>   "660": "102", "44": "2.0", "10066": "20180320-08:08:35.038", "29":
>   "4", "50": "JPNIK01", "22": "101"}

The fields used for searching is order_id (tag 37) and trd_date(tag 75). I will create the schema with the two fields added to it

```
<field name="37" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="75" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

At the moment I can get the result by: `http://192.168.112.141:8983/solr/fix_messages/select?q=37:337912000000002`
where 37 is the order_id and  337912000000002 is the value to search in field of "37"

The result I get is:

```
 {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":6,
    "params":{
      "q":"37:337912000000002"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "122":["20180320-08:08:35.038"],
        "49":["VIPER"],
        "382":[0],
        "151":[1.0],
        "9":[653],
        "10071":["20180320-08:08:35.088"],
        "15":["JPY"],
        "56":["XSVC"],
        "54":[1],
        "10202":["APMKTMAKING"],
........
```

I need to show the result like below:

1. the order_id: the term of "order_id" must be displayed instead of its actual tag 37;
2. the trd_date: the term of "trd_date" must be displayed in the result;
3. the whole message: the whole and raw message must be displayed in the result;
4. the two fields of order_id and trd_date must be highlighted.

Can anyone tell me how do I do it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should add the names of the columns when you're building the JSON structure, or create a small script that changes the keys in the JSON file and outputs a new structure for you. There really isn't any way around that - unless you can have the mapping in your front end layer. If you need the whole message - that depends on if you want the JSON or FIX message - but again, you'll need to preprocess it to add it to the JSON file. "Highlighting the field" - regular Solr highlighting can be enabled with `hl.fl`.

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer, please repost your comment as answer and I will accept it, another new question here is you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741782/how-to-restrict-users-solr-searching-scope-based-on-his-her-entitlement

Answer (score 0):

You should add the names of the columns when you're building the JSON structure, or create a small script that changes the keys in the JSON file and outputs a new structure for you. There really isn't any way around that - unless you can have the mapping in your front end layer.

If you need the whole message - that depends on if you want the JSON or FIX message - but again, you'll need to preprocess it to add it to the JSON file.

For "Highlighting the field" - regular Solr highlighting can be enabled with `hl.fl`.